# Date not getting parsed in beamSql

Tags: apache-beam

I have this below error :

```
SEVERE: 2018-03-17T17:15:42.272Z: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'BeamRecord [dataValues=[2/12/2017], dataType=BeamRecordSqlType [fieldNames=[c0], fieldTypes=[12]]]' with coder 'org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.BeamRecordCoder@56ce2595'.
```

I have specified **dataValues=[2/12/2017]** as TIMESTAMP datatype. [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/)

Any idea whats going wrong here ?

Comment: I was able to solve this error, Week field was not declared in one of my class files. But still null value is getting passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you're using incorrect type for the `TIMESTAMP` field. `BeamRecord` expects a value of type `java.util.Date` in the `TIMESTAMP` fields.

If your input is coming from JSON, for example, you might need to parse the timestamp field using `java.text.DateFormat`, see example [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/701f531466d93bb82229e856444781627256a0e9/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlDslBase.java#L87).

If you're specifying the `TIMESTAMP` in the query, then try specifying the timestamp in this format: `TIMESTAMP '1999-02-22 01:01:58'`. See examples [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a13c7d9177c34017955cbfbfc29a7f4a698047c1/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/integrationtest/BeamSqlDateFunctionsIntegrationTest.java#L57).

Comment: Correct, I parsed the date using DateFormat method and it worked. Thanks.